# Using the ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, shopping-cart

I have made an `ArrayList` of type `CartItem`, basically it stores all the `CartItems` in one list.

Now once a `CartItem` has already been added, instead of adding the same `CartItem` again, it will increase its quantity by one, rather than adding the element again in the list.

```
public ArrayList<CartItem> Items = new ArrayList<CartItem>();
public void AddItem(int productId)
{

    CartItem newItem = new CartItem(productId);

    if (Items.equals(newItem))
    {
        System.out.println("equal");
        for (CartItem item:Items)
        {
            if (item.Equals(newItem))
            {

                item.Quantity++;
                return;
            }
       }
   }
    else
   {
        newItem.Quantity = 1;
        Items.add(newItem);
   }
}
```

the cartItem constructor is as follows

public CartItem(int productId)
    {

```
    this.ProductId = productId;
    this.prod = new Product(productId);
    this.Quantity =1;
}
```

Instead of showing, Books , 3
its showing Books 1, Books 1, Books 1

CartItem.Equals(Object) Function

```
public boolean Equals(CartItem item)
    {
      if(item.prod.Id == this.prod.Id)
      {
           return true;
      }
      return false;
     }
```

Comment: Without actual code, there's not much anyone can do but guess. Please post your actual code.

Comment: Show CartItem.equals() please, that's the point.

Comment: it still isnt working :@

Comment: Are you sure that's all of your code? ShoppingCart doesn't look like it should compile

Comment: No this is only the part that I have to show for you guys to find out the mistake I''m doing.

Comment: Is there any more to your ShoppingCart class? I can see many things wrong with it as it is shown above, it seems like you've given a method body out of context? Please update it so that we can see exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your class ShoppingCart should be like this:

```
   public ShoppingCart{

        ArrayList<CartItem> Items = new ArrayList<CartItem>();

        public void AddItem(int productId)
        {
        CartItem newItem = new CartItem(productId);


            for (CartItem item:Items)
            {
                  if (item.Equal(newItem))
                  {
                    item.Quantity++;
                    return;
            }
          }


            newItem.Quantity = 1;
            Items.add(newItem);

        }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Without the code there is very little that we can do. But here are a few pointers:

1. Override `equals()` and `hashcode()` in your `CartItem` class.
2. Use generic `ArrayList<CartItem`> instead of the raw type.

A possible version of your required equals() methods might be:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
        final CartItem other = (CartItem) obj;

        if (this.prodID != other.prodID)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: BTW, ArrayList is an implementation, you should use the List interface whenever possible: public List<CartItem> Items = new ArrayList<CartItem>(); . Declare and pass List and let the caller decide if he wants an ArrayList, a LinkedList or whatever...

Comment: @ymajoros...Rightly said...I was talking about the implementation though...:)

Comment: I believe only proper `equals()` implementation is required for this particular case. `hashcode()` would be used only if `CartItem` is put into a `Map`.

Answer (score 3):

Look what you compare:

```
ArrayList<CartItem> Items = new ArrayList<CartItem>();
CartItem newItem = new CartItem(productId);
if (Items.equals(newItem))
```

Items (ArrayList object) is never equal newItem (CartItem object)

edited:
What you should do is:

1. Change Items.equals(newItem) to Items.contains(newItem)
2. Your equals in CartItem is incorrect, change it to something like that:

I've kept your naming but it isn't correct :)

```
public boolean equal(CartItem item) {
    if (!(item instanceof CarItem)) {
        return false;
    }

    return item.itm.Id == itm.Id;
}
```

Comment: but in the CartItem constructor, i am initializing all the variables.

Comment: but Items is ArrayList and newItem is CartItem (different objects) so it is not equals - you have always false here

Comment: but once the newCartItem is created (in else bracked for first time), it is being added into the ArrayList. so on the second time, when the same item is being added, it should return true!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling:

```
if (Items.equals(newItem))
```

ie. .equals() on a List of CartItems.

I am guessing that will never evaluate to true for you, hence why you are never seeing an old item being updated.

You should really re-thingk
 - Implement a proper, java .eqauls() method on CartItem
 - you can then use List.contains(CartItem) to check if an item exists.

A better solution is to store your items in a HashMap (keyed by Item.id) to make look-up easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
  ArrayList<CartItem> Items = new ArrayList<CartItem>();
if (Items.equals(newItem))
```

You are comparing newItem with your List? I suspect his will always fail as I do not think newItem is the same as an empty ArrayList, however your code snippet looks incomplete, so I cannot be 100%.

EDIT:

CartItem.Equal looks wrong:

```
  public boolean Equal(CartItem item)
    {

        final CartItem a = new CartItem(item.Id);
          if (this.itm.Id != a.ProductId)
          {
              return false;
          }
      return true;
    }
```

Why construct a new object here?
This method should be comparing the parameter item with the current CartItem object (this).
Eg:

```
     public boolean Equal(CartItem item){
          return item.getId() == this.getId();//Implement a getId() method
    }
```

I would re-visit your CartItem class - why is there a quantity field? Is this class actually supposed to represent a collection of cart items?

Also, why have you not overridden the Object.equals(Object o) method?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the
CartItem newItem = new CartItem(productId);

in my snippet. thanks

Comment: You should also get used to the convention that methods and instance variables in Java are written in camelCase. It's only a convention but if you work with other Java programmers they will probably get annoyed if you do not follow it, as it could lead them to mis-read your code.

Comment: Quantity exists, because a customer can by 4 books, or 5 shoes of the same item.

and why should it be overrideen, the method name id different, .Equal() in cartItem class and .equals() for object

Answer (score 1):

Your equals method on CartItem is wrong.

EDIT:

I can see you have changed its name to Equal. But your Equal method takes a int but when you use it you pass a CartItem to it. I would not think this compiles.

Comment: Hmm..some parts of the code were typo'd. I think its correct now

Comment: It takes a CartItem now..it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a change to your approach.

Forget the CartItem, and just match up your Product to an Integer (quantity) via a Map

You shouldn't need productId either, as that SHOULD be a member of Product.

```
class Cart {
   private Map<Product,Integer> cart;

   public Cart() {
       cart = new HashMap<Product,Integer>();
   }

   public int getQuantity(Product p) {
       if(cart.contains(p)) return cart.get(p);
       return 0; // not in the cart
   }

   public void add(Product p) {
      add(p,0);
   }

   public void add(Product p, int q) {
      if(q < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add negative amounts");
      cart.put(p,getQuantity(p) + q);
   }

   // removes are left as exercise for the reader

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList uses **CartItem.equals()** to determine match or not, so you could check CartItem.equals() implementation. BTW, it's nothing with `hashcode()`.

EDIT: `Equals` is not `equals`, parameter is also incorrect. Use `@Override` on `equals()` to ensure correctness.

Comment: Instead of showing, Books, 3
its showing
Books 1, Books 1, Books 1

so its because of a problem with matching the list with cartitem

Comment: I used equals, but the same prob is occuring

Comment: You STILL haven't shown us the CODE for the `CartItem.equals(Object)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for `Items.equals(newItem)` you need to check for `Items.contains(newItem)` and of course override `equals` in `CartItem` to check product id. However what your solution is doing is iterating over the List of CartItems once in the `contains` method and again to find the actual `CartItem`. This should raise alarm bells about your choice of data structure.

What you are trying to do is match product ids to their quantity, this suggests that a Map might be a better data structure. Using a Map would give you an implementation a bit more like:

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> Items = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
public void AddItem(int productId)
{
    if (Items.containsKey(productId))
    {
        int count = Items.get(productId);
        Items.put(productId, count+1);
   }
    else
   {
        Items.put(productId, 1);
   }
}
```